# Как сделать условие php? в этом случае!

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Этот код выводит woocomerce в wp,
как из этого кода сделать условие если допустим есть вывод цены (это его работа выводить цену) то выводим одно, если нету ничего то выводим другое.!

```
<?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($product->get_price_html() != ''){
    цена не указана
} else {
   цена указана
}
```

Comment: Arendach, в условии сказано наоборот. )) Если поле не пустое, то... иначе...

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php echo empty($product->get_price_html()) ? 'drugoe' : $product->get_price_html() ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Написал бы так:

```
<?php if ($product->get_price_html() != '') : ?>
  <p><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></p>
<?php else : ?>
  <p>Что-то другое...<p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Разумеется, параграфы можно заменить на любые нужные вам теги.